# How to play music on both Hearphone connector and Bluetooth on iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, bluetooth, headphones

Is there a way to play music through Headphone connector (HI-FI system) and Bluetooth (Wireless speaker in different place) **simultaneously** ?
It seems that I can only choose one or the other, but it seems so simple there might be a way to do so.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  There's several questions and answers on this site dealing with multiple audio streams.  Have you searched for the answers already provided?  What errors are you getting?  Please see [ask] for important info on asking questions here.

Answer (score 1):

Its no posible (whitout jailbreack). The cheapest form to do that is: buy two "airport express" (off second hand because Apple dont sales any more), and use airplay. In that way, connect the plug off audio to airport, &, in your iphone can see the two devices (or the cuantity thath you showld buy) to send music at all them.

Comment: Too bad :-/ I remember now why I'm not an Apple fan :D Thanks for the tips anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible with the native OS.

This is possible though of you have 2 speakers and both compatible with AirPlay 2. Whilst not giving the exact same effect it is similar in some ways to what you want.

Any device with this logo on the packaging should work with AirPlay 2.

[image: logo]

Also, your iPhone must be running iOS 11.4 or later.

To view the full requirements go [here.](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT208728#airplay2)

Then view [this article](https://support.apple.com/HT208744) on how to stream to multiple speakers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm running on the last iOS but I'm not sure my Speaker is compatible. Maybe this logo only appears on Apple products ?

Comment: I tried Air Play but it seems the only thing I can do is switching from a speaker to another. In my case, I want the same music flux in 2 separate rooms (I'm owning a restaurant).

Comment: @GrégorySantana see this article here for multiple speakers: https://support.apple.com/HT208744#iOS

Comment: That's what I did but it seems I can only switch from one to another.